# Featured images have disappeared in the Trending section only of my website

Tags: post-thumbnails

I just now noticed this appears above the Featured and Trending options at the bottom of the Edit Post page. I really don't think it was there all along. Could it be the problem? Can you suggest what the problem might be and how to fix it? Thanks!!

```
function dn_add_rss_image() { global $post; $output = ''; if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) { $thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_ID, 'thumbnail' ); $output .= '
```

Comment: Hi Jacob Peattie, thanks for the edit. Can you suggest what the problem might be as to why the pictures are only missing from one section? I would really appreciate it!! Thanks!!

Comment: Does that function really have end with an unclosed string, `$output .= '` ? that might interfere with any HTML after that in the file. Are there no add_action lines for it? (and does it really have no line breaks?)